# how to display PIL image with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do some video stream from my raspberry pi over the wifi. I used pygame, because i also have to use gamepad in my project. Unfortunately I stucked on displaying received frame. Shortly: i get jpeg frame, open it with PIL, convert to string - after that i can load image from string

```
image_stream = io.BytesIO()
...
frame_1 = Image.open(image_stream) 
f = StringIO.StringIO()
frame_1.save(f, "JPEG")
data = f.getvalue()
frame = pygame.image.fromstring(frame_1,image_len,"RGB")
screen.fill(white)
screen.blit(frame, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

and error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\defau_000\Desktop\server.py", line 57, in <module>
    frame = pygame.image.fromstring(frame_1,image_len,"RGB")
TypeError: must be str, not instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `pygame.image.fromstring` has to be a `str`.

So when `frame_1` is your PIL image, convert it to a string with `tostring`, and load this string with `pygame.image.fromstring`.

You have to know the size of the image for this to work.

```
raw_str = frame_1.tostring("raw", 'RGBA')
pygame_surface = pygame.image.fromstring(raw_str, size, 'RGBA')
```

Answer (score 4):

Sloth's answer is incorrect for newer versions of Pygame.  The `tostring()` definition is deprecated.  Here is a working variant for Python 3.6, PIL 5.1.0, Pygame 1.9.3:

```
raw_str = frame_1.tobytes("raw", 'RGBA')
pygame_surface = pygame.image.fromstring(raw_str, size, 'RGBA')
```